# If i want to run another script in web driver, do i need to create project, package and class for that?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: Here, i just opened the url in FF browser using this script..If i want to run another script,do i need to create project, package and class for that ?I'm new to selenium web driver..Can you guys please help..]
[Here, i just opened the url in FF browser using this script..If i want to run another script,do i need to create project, package and class for that ?I'm new to selenium web driver..Can you guys  please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you run your script within `main` method that is an entry point of the whole Java program. You do not need to create a separate project of course. Regarding other aspects it might depend on how you'd like to organize your code.

Technically you may go in one of the following ways (just the examples):

- describe different scripts in different methods and then call them from `main` method
- Have different classes each with their own `main` method holding the script
- Utilize some unit test frameworks like JUnit or TestNg and keep different scripts in different methods of your test classes (which have to be marked in some special way)

Whatever way you will use you should also consider the practices of code re-usage so that you define some common code (like creating web driver) and script code that would re-use that common-code.

I can suggest the following architecture if you run the tests from `main`:

**1. Implement interface:**

```java
public interface IStep {

    void take(WebDriver driver);

}
```

**2. Implement test runner with tests** (tests can actually be decoupled from the runner, however not to waste time I coupled them)

```java
public class Test {

    WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().takeStep((wd)->{test1(wd);});
        new Test().takeStep((wd)->{test2(wd);});
    }

    private void before(){
        System.out.println("Starting up test..");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/Dev/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    private void after(){
        System.out.println("Shutting down test..");
        if(driver != null){
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    public void takeStep(IStep step){
        before();
        try{
            step.take(driver);
            System.out.println("Test Passed");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Test Failed: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            after();
        }
    }

    public static void test1(WebDriver wd){
        wd.get("http://google.com");
        System.out.println("Search input in Google");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input"));
    }

    public static void test2(WebDriver wd){
        wd.get("http://sqa.stackexchange.com");
        System.out.println("Search input in SO");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input"));
    }

}
```

In this example to add new test you should do the following (for example we'd like to add `test3`):

**Add new method with your new test code**

```
public static void test3(WebDriver wd){
    // Your another script
}
```

**Add execution to the `main`**

```
new Test().takeStep((wd)->{test3(wd);});
```

**P.S.** - You need to learn some Java concepts to completely understand this code, such as:

- [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html)
- [Exceptions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptions-in-java/)
- [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)